# Is there a way to use multiple HTML files for a single Shiny App?

Tags: javascript, html, css, r, shiny

I have been trying to build entire UI with HTML for Shiny App. However, I'm facing a problem where if I want to add navbar that could connect to multiple html files, it's not working.

Reference that I've been following: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/html-ui.html

Below are my codes:-

My App.r

```
# Define server logic for random distribution app ----
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  # Reactive expression to generate the requested distribution ----
  # This is called whenever the inputs change. The output functions
  # defined below then use the value computed from this expression
  d <- reactive({
    dist <- switch(input$dist,
                   norm = rnorm,
                   unif = runif,
                   lnorm = rlnorm,
                   exp = rexp,
                   rnorm)
    
    dist(input$n)
  })
  
  # Generate a plot of the data ----
  # Also uses the inputs to build the plot label. Note that the
  # dependencies on the inputs and the data reactive expression are
  # both tracked, and all expressions are called in the sequence
  # implied by the dependency graph.
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    dist <- input$dist
    n <- input$n
    
    hist(d(),
         main = paste("r", dist, "(", n, ")", sep = ""),
         col = "#75AADB", border = "white")
  })
  
  # Generate a summary of the data ----
  output$summary <- renderPrint({
    summary(d())
  })
  
  # Generate an HTML table view of the head of the data ----
  output$table <- renderTable({
    head(data.frame(x = d()))
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = htmlTemplate("template.html"), server)
```

My template.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="shared/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="shared/shiny.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="shared/shiny.css"/>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <!-- A grey horizontal navbar that becomes vertical on small screens -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-light">

          <!-- Links -->
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="template.html">Link 1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="templatepg2.html">Link 2</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 3</a>
            </li>
          </ul>

        </nav>
    </header>

  <h1>HTML UI</h1>

  <p>
    <label>Distribution type:</label><br />
    <select name="dist">
      <option value="norm">Normal</option>
      <option value="unif">Uniform</option>
      <option value="lnorm">Log-normal</option>
      <option value="exp">Exponential</option>
    </select>
  </p>

  <p>

    <label>Number of observations:</label><br />
    <input type="number" name="n" value="500" min="1" max="1000" />

  </p>

  <h3>Summary of data:</h3>
  <pre id="summary" class="shiny-text-output"></pre>

  <h3>Plot of data:</h3>
  <div id="plot" class="shiny-plot-output"
       style="width: 100%; height: 300px"></div>

  <h3>Head of data:</h3>
  <div id="table" class="shiny-html-output"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

My templatepg2.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="shared/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="shared/shiny.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="shared/shiny.css"/>
</head>

<body>

  <h1>HTML UI Page 2!</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

**Is there a way for me to actually connect multiple HTML files to a single Shiny App?**

Comment: I don't fully understand: an html document generally only has `<!DOCTYPE html>` *once*, with one `<html>` block, etc. Are you talking about inserting `templatepg2.html` as an iframe within the main? Or do you want the user to be able to choose which template they want?

Comment: I want to let the user to choose the different template based on the tab they chose. if they chose <link 1> it will direct to template.html, if they chose <link 2> it will direct to templatepg2.html/ does that answers your question?

Basically I need a navbar that links to multiple html files for a single Shiny App.

Comment: You mention tabs but there are not tabsets defined in either template. What do you mean by "tab"? Regardless, your `<a href=...>Link 1</a>` (and `Link 2`) will navigate away from the current page, that has nothing to do with templates. What you are asking for is not really how most shiny apps are structured, and honestly I'm a bit confused what your expected UX might be.

Comment: Sorry @r2evans if I make you even more confused, let me properly rephrase my sentence. I want to create a navbar for my Shiny App & I'm using entire HTML file as the UI. Based from my understanding, in order to have a navbar that could link to multiple pages, I need to state the specific `href= example.html`. However when I try to implement this, it doesn't work. so I've been wondering if there is any solution on this, or perhaps Shiny doesn't support the structure that I plan to apply.

Comment: "Shiny app" and "multiple HTML pages" are not compatible. However, you can use tabsets or dynamic UI (e.g., `shiny::renderUI`, though that's a bit draconian for what you need) within a single app.

Comment: I see, alright then. Thank you so much @r2evans for the clarification. Appreciate it!

Comment: What are you intending `Link 2` to do? Where does your `templatepg2.html` appear in the shiny app? I don't think it "replaces all HTML components" (which would remove the navbar links), I wonder if it is intended just to "hide" some components of the main page while something else is in front. I suspect you can use tabsets (with or without href tags), please see https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/tabsets.html.

Comment: apologies on that @r2evans , I missed out on the navbar links on `templatepg2.html` and Yes I initially planned to replace all HTML components

Comment: You could also see this as it matches you multiple page topic. At least for you information as it's still experimental: https://colinfay.me/brochure-r-package/

Answer (score 0):

I've the same problematic as you, and just find out something new.
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/shiny.router/index.html, I think, it might help. Gonna use it, right now!!!

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.